# meteor loginbuttons no longer appearing

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, meteorite

I was creating a quick mock-up of a web app with some friends, and wanted to use a log in system.  I have just read and completed the Discover Meteor, and decided I would just use their simple login, as I am using bootstrap as well.  But after a quick search on Atmosphere I saw that there was now a accounts-ui-bootstrap-3, so I decided I would try it out, and use the bootstrap-3 package for some styling I had.

Once I installed it I threw my {{loginButtons}} in my navbar which looked as follows:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li>{{loginButtons}}</li>
  <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now when I completed my navbar it looked as I had planned, and I had a link for log in.  But for some reason it was simply a link and no drop down would appear. Also there were no errors for the page in my developer console, nor when I clicked the button.  So I tried moving some things but nothing worked, so since I was in a hurry I decided it may be easier just to use the previous dropdown I had used in the book.  So I used this to remove the package:

```
mrt remove accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
mrt remove bootstrap-3
```

and added the following:

```
mrt add accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown
mrt add accounts-password
mrt add bootstrap
```

Once completed I went back to my page expecting to see a link, but now not only was there no drop down, there was no link to click.  I checked my html, which was back to the format I showed earlier with the {{loginbuttons}} and I had just had the link with no drop down working in the accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 package.  So I tried for a while to fix it but to no avail.  I checked my console again and had absolutely no error.

Confused I now went back to the other package again by typing the following:

```
mrt remove accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown
mrt remove accounts-password
mrt remove bootstrap
mrt add accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
mrt add bootstrap-3
```

And when I got there, again no link would appear.  But then it went further that even when I cycled backwards through various Git commits I had made, I can never get to a point in time in which it will now appear.  No matter which stage of the project I enter, I cannot get the loginButtons to ever appear on my navbar.  I only got an error at one point when both accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown and accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 were on my project at the same time, the error telling me I had two functions called logginbuttons at the same time (as expected).  Once I removed one of the packages, it went away and again I had no error.

Now I could just fully restart my project, and try to quickly replicate my code to the new one, unfortunately I hadn't put the accounts option in till a bit late so I'll have to cycle over my last 2 days of work, but that not really a big deal, I just want to see if someone can let me know if I did something wrong, or maybe jut gain a further understanding of meteor and meteorite.  Thanks! :)

EDIT
I apologize I should have also filled in that I am changing bootstrap versions as well when I was switching back and forth.  whenever I am using the bootstrap 3 login menu I switch to bootstrap 3 and remove 2.  When I am using the bootstrap 2 menu, I install bootstrap 2 and remove bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible your project's Meteor install has gotten into some strange inconsistent state. I've solved problems like this before by deleting `project_dir/.meteor/local/` (I recommend moving it to a temp directory instead) then running `mrt` again and letting Meteor re-bootstrap itself.

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion!  I tried this after reading your response, but to no avail.  It reinstalled the local directory and its components, but still no link appearing.  Thanks for the help though! :)

Answer (score 6):

Change the line:

```
<li>{{loginButtons}}</li>
```

to:

```
<li>{{> loginButtons}}</li>
```

Comment: That's to say, treat it as a helper not as an expression. This has changed at some point, I think. Certain tutorials, eg. versions of Discover Meteor suggest using the top line.

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem with mixing Bootstrap 2 and Bootstrap 3.
The styling for accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown is meant for Bootstrap 2 at the moment.
The official meteor package uses Bootstrap 2.
None of the packages that style the accounts include Bootstrap for you.

To get it to work you can use:

```
mrt add bootstrap-3
mrt add accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
```

Comment: Hi Pent, thanks for the help!.  I should have said that I am using bootstrap-3 and did use it with the accounts-ui-bootstrap-3.  Every time I used accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 I also reinstalled bootstrap-3.  Sorry that was my bad I should have posted it in the question, and I will fix it now.  Thanks though :)